# Postgresql - how to call procedure, name which is into variable

Tags: sql, postgresql, stored-procedures, dynamic-sql, procedural-programming

**how can I call procedure from variable**

**var** proc_name := 'proc1()'

**call** proc_name;

Answer (score 0):

```
\set proc_name 'proc1()'

call :proc_name;
```

Comment: Try to provide more details in your answer about how it solves the OP question.

Comment: Just connect to psql and run the commands attached. Let me know if more details required.